# Is there a left join in django.extra() which can help me to join tables without any relationship in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
class Ordman(models.Model):
    pcod = models.CharField(db_column="PCOD", max_length=6)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "ORDMAN"


class Shademst(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(db_column="CODE", primary_key=True, max_length=6)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "SHADEMST"
```

These both are connected without any relationship and I need to fire a left join query with the help of extra() in ORM in django but the join I can apply is inner join so can anyone help me to figure out how to apply left join in it. The database is a legacy database so can't do changes on it

Comment: What's the join you'd be doing? Or rather, if they _were_ regular Django ForeignKeys, what are you looking for?

Comment: Actually, The PCOD in Ordman may or may not have data in it, but I still need to fire a JOIN query, I wanna do a LEFT JOIN, so if the PCOD doesn't have data still the join queries fire and bring the data.

I need to fire 
select * from ORDMAN LEFT JOIN SHADEMST on Ordman.shcd =  SHADEMST.code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment

> The PCOD in Ordman may or may not have data in it, but I still need to fire a JOIN query, I wanna do a LEFT JOIN, so if the PCOD doesn't have data still the join queries fire and bring the data. I need to fire 
>   `select * from ORDMAN LEFT JOIN SHADEMST on Ordman.shcd = SHADEMST.code`

I'd suggest simply editing the `pcod` field definition on `Ordman` to actually *be* a foreign key, something like

```
pcod = models.ForeignKey(Shademst, db_column="PCOD", to_field="code")
```

and Django should be smart enough to infer the 1:N relationship and let you do joins as per usual.

Comment: I can't do changes in the database

Comment: You're not doing changes in the database, you're just changing how Django interprets it. Your models are marked `managed = False`, so Django's migrations will always leave them alone.

Comment: Okay, will try it out